# Is there a program/script to modify .conf files?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to modify a file like `/etc/gdm/custom.conf` **from the shell or a script**.

```
# GDM configuration storage
[xdmcp]
[debug]
[daemon]
AutomaticLoginEnable=true;
AutomaticLogin=username;
```

But the idea is that I can add a line to a section and it check if the section is defined, (add the definition if not), the property is defined, let it undefine (erase the line), (and delete the section header if there is no property defined), etc...

I didn't find anything except [gconftool-2](http://projects.gnome.org/gconf/) but it do not explain how to modify other files. (there is a shema file there).

Comment: `conf` files do not have a fixed markup of any kind. Compare f.e. the `/etc/gdm/custom.conf` to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` or `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: as bobby states there is no such thing as .conf syntax but lots of scripting languages do have good config parser modules. you may achive what you are looking for with a short self written script. e.g. in python or perl

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**[Augeas](http://augeas.net/)** is a: **A command line tool to manipulate configuration from the shell (and shell scripts).** (among other things)

It uses lenses to transform every file to xml, give special tools to edit them, and use the lenses to write the file back in native format.

Comment: This is _exactly_ what I was looking for.  Easy to install, easy to use.  Just a note, this tool is in the default Ubuntu repos.

Comment: And what you need is the `desktop.aug` module.

Answer (score 5):

You could try crudini

```
crudini --set /etc/gdm/custom.conf daemon AutomaticLoginEnable 'true;'
```

Comment: This is the simplest and most versatile solution, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to edit the custom.conf file to auto-login a certain user on my embedded system. Interestingly enough, the Jetson Xavier boards automatically have `git` installed and I could simply do the following:

```
git config --file=/etc/gdm3/custom.conf daemon.AutomaticLoginEnable true
git config --file=/etc/gdm3/custom.conf daemon.AutomaticLogin ${USERNAME}
```

I put these two lines in one of my packages `debian/package-name.postinst` and voilà, it worked.

Note: The `daemon` part is a section name (i.e. `[daemon]`).

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

Some of the config file's use INI file headers. So you could use any INI parsers to do the validation and operations.

For Example, In python, you can use [ConfigParser](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html)

In Perl , user [ConfigAbstract](http://search.cpan.org/~avajadi/Config-Abstract-0.13/Ini/Ini.pm)

Comment: That sound good, but I've got to program for that to work (I know perl and python are easy, but I do not use them).
With this in mind it should be easy to make a script/program that do what I want to do, but this is what I don't want to do...    
    
So I want to have a program that I can write (in the shell):    



 `configeditor "configfile" "section.item=value"`

Comment: I think I have to downvote this because, as Bobby mentioned in a comment on the question, there are a lot of config files that don't follow the INI format. But for those that do, this is the solution I'd go with.

Comment: So the answer is NO, there isn't a program/script to achieve this, but can easyly be made for every config file.

Answer (score -2):

In `vi`, search for entries with `/`. Press `n` to find the next entry. Edit the files at will.

Comment: Asker is asking for an automated solution like adding a setting with a command. `addconfig /configfile.conf --key=website --value=SuperUser.com`